# How to drop columns from a comma separated string from a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a comma separated list of columns like :

```
@cols =  '[FirstName],[LastName],[Address]'
```

When i drop these columns as

```
  ALTER TABLE #TempTable DROP COLUMN [FirstName],[LastName],[Address]
```

it is working. But if "Address" column is not there in "#TempTable" table then i am getting an error.
I know we can drop individual columns as:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns
WHERE Name = N'columnName' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tableName'))
BEGIN
PRINT 'Your Column Exists'
END
```

But how can i loop through that string and see if it exists or not?

Thanks

Comment: Google "SQL String parsing"

Answer (score 0):

```
    @temCols = '1,asdfasd,2werw,3,5,8';    

    WHILE len(@temCols) > 0
                            BEGIN
                                set @column = left(@temCols, charindex(',', @temCols+',')-1)

                            set @temCols = stuff(@temCols, 1, charindex(',', @temCols+','), '')
print @column;

                        END
```